# php ckeditor version 4 adding custom fonts

Tags: ckeditor

Iam working on php code igniter with version 4 ck editor.
Trying to add custom fonts.

I have tried adding the following code to ckeditor/config.js

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{
config.contentsCss = 'fonts.css';
config.font_names = 'Dekers/dekers_true' + config.font_names;
}
```

the font adds to the drop but is not applied to text